# Question related to integrality of field of fractions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This is actually not a problem, but it's a statement which is taken for granted and I don't know how to prove it. Hope some one can help me. I really appreciate:

> > Suppose $A$ is subring of ring $B$, and $A$, $B$ are integral domains. If $B$ is integral over $A$, prove that field of fraction of $B$ is algebraic over field of fraction of $A$. Does the converse remain true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a well-known fact from field theory that if $a$ is algebraic, then $a^{-1}$ is also algebraic. And for field extensions algebraic = integral. This shows that every integral extension of integral domains induces an algebraic extension of their fraction fields. Of course the converse is not true (consider $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ for example).

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. Can you please more clearer on "This shows that every integral extension of integral domains induces an algebraic extension of their fraction fields"? Thanks so much.

Comment: Here is what I try, but I'm not sure whether I did it right: An element of $B$ has the form  $b/1.(s/1)^{-1}$. But as you said, we can prove that $b/1, (s/1)^{-1}$ is algebraic in field of fraction of $A$, so is their product.

Answer (score 3):

[I'm using $K(\phantom{x})$ to denote taking the fraction field.]

The elements of $B$ are certainly algebraic over $K(A)$, and for a general algebraic extension $L/K$ the elements of $L$ algebraic over $K$ form a field. If this fact is unknown to you then it would be a good exercise.

If I'm understanding you correctly, the last part has no chance of being true. A silly example: $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}[\tfrac12]$. The fraction fields are the same!